# Python Dataframe fillna with value on left column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have an excel spreadsheet where there are merged cells.

[image]

I would like to build a dictionary of Product_ID - Category - Country.

But for that I need to get, I believe, Python to be able to read an excel file with horizontally merged cells.

```
import pandas as pd

excel_sheet = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Product_Sales_Database.xlsx, 'Product IDs')
```

However the returned dataframe is this:

[image]

My question is, how can I fill the nan values in the dataframe, with the values on the left column?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].ffill()
```

Comment: So easy, thank you so much @Juan C.
I was trying df.fillna(), and tried the different methods, but none was doing what I needed.

Comment: `ffill` (and its counterpart `bfill`) are very useful in many situations, glad it helped !

Answer (score 0):

I understand, that the question is more than 2 yo, and the best answer is correct, but if you want to fill NaNs of the whole Frame, you can use:

```
df.T.ffill().T
```